# Delay Hover In Dropdown Menu Javascript CSS

Tags: javascript, css, menu, hover, dropdown

I am having some trouble with creating a hoverable dropdown menu inside a navigation bar. I am pretty new to javascript & css but have background in other languages. I cannot figure out how to delay my dropdown menus to become visible. Right now, my dropdown menu instantly shows the moment you hover over the parent menu. I am using this for a description template and it would be ideal to solve this problem.

I have tried using transitions and tweaking my code around, I can't find the proper way to do this. I suspect one reason is for the display: block. I have left out any code that was used in an attempt to implement the delay. This is the original code of menus.

Here is my code:

```
                        ul{
                            border-style: groove;
                            padding: 0;
                            list-style: none;
                            background: #f2f2f2;
                        }
                        ul li{
                            display: inline-block;
                            position: relative;
                            line-height: 21px;
                            text-align: left;
                        }
                        ul li a{
                            display: block;
                            padding: 8px 25px;
                            color: #333;
                            text-decoration: none;

                        }
                        ul li a:hover{
                            color: #fff;
                    background-color:#939393;
                  
                        }
                        ul li ul.dropdown{
                            min-width: 100%; /* Set width of the dropdown */
                            background: #f2f2f2;
                            display: none;
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: 999;
                            left: 0;
                        }
                        ul li:hover ul.dropdown{
                            display: block; /* Display the dropdown */
                        }
                        ul li ul.dropdown li{
                            display: block;
                        }
```

Comment: do you want it to display slowly, like fade in? or just wait some time then imediately show?

Comment: I would want it to wait some time and then slightly fade in. Maybe a .2 second fade. So I guess a bit of both. Right now it immediately shows the drop down menu and for it being part of a description wrapper, sometimes the user would want to scroll down the page to more important information without any menus popping up.

Comment: well, if you want a fade type effect, you would probably have to css `transition` the `opacity` property from 0 to 1. You cannot `transition` (animate) the css `display` property

Comment: Okay thank you for the info. I am trying to implement that but I am having trouble still. Any idea how I could implement that with the current code I have?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

```
ul li ul.dropdown.show{
  display:block;
}
```

In JavaScript:

```
const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul.dropdown');
for(let q of dropdowns){
  q.onmouseenter = function(){
    setTimeout(()=>{ 
      this.classList.add('show'); 
    }, 1000);
  }
  q.onmouseleave = function(){
    this.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
```

This is just a basic concept. I would use a CSS `transition`.